# How i can import a external database sqlite in android app

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I wanna use a external database `sqlite` in my android app.

I have copied a database in assets folder in my java android project (database.db.zip) but i can't use this database with normal guides on web.

i have create this class

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "parole.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

}

i how i can use this for reading my database ?

Comment: copy it somewhere to the file system?

Comment: Please refer http://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ to use existing db.

Comment: Use [SqliteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) library.

Comment: Don't zip it; this is done automatically for the entire .apk.